# How do I use this python script to decrypt an encrypted file?

Tags: python, encryption

Sorry to waste everybody's time because I don't know python. I use `jrnl`a lot to write journal entries, and a while ago I encrypted a file that I know the password to, but don't know how to use this script (provided by the developer) to decrypt.  I realized I had to make it executable to use it (genius right) but then got an error when I used it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usr/src/jrnl_decrypt", line 16, in 
    with open(args.filepath, 'rb') as f:
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'filepath'

Here's the script. I also found an alternative one in older documentation. It's below the larger script.

```
import argparse
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import getpass
import hashlib
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("~", help="old-journal-encrypted.txt")
args = parser.parse_args()

pwd = getpass.getpass()
key = hashlib.sha256(pwd.encode('utf-8')).digest()

with open(args.filepath, 'rb') as f:
 ciphertext = f.read()

crypto = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, ciphertext[:16])
plain = crypto.decrypt(ciphertext[16:])
plain = plain.strip(plain[-1:])
plain = plain.decode("utf-8")
print(plain)

# Python script to manually decrypt jrnl files




//Alt script

import hashlib, Crypto.Cipher
key = hashlib.sha256(my_password).digest()
with open("old-journal-encrypted.txt") as f:
 cipher = f.read()
 crypto = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv = cipher[:16])
 plain = crypto.decrypt(cipher[16:])
 plain = plain.strip(plain[-1])
 plain = plain.decode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: you're not wasting anyone's time. None of us known everything from the beginning ^^

In this line `parser.add_argument("~", help="old-journal-encrypted.txt")` you are adding your argument as ~, so you may use it as args.~ (if it was the case). That's not intuitive, so try changin that line to `parser.add_argument("filepath", help="old-journal-encrypted.txt")`. After that try to run the script again.

Edit: you're not setting the value with the 'help parameter', it's just a tooltip. You must pass the value when you call the script I.E: `python my_prog.py old-journal-encrypted.txt`. Make sure that the file is reacheable as well

Hope this helps you!

P.S: You have an example [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#example) in case you still have some doubts (don't hesitate to add a comment as well if that's the case ^^)